# JQuery.UI.Tabs default selected by TabID

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, javascript

Is there any simple way to specify the default selected tab on `jQueryUI` Tabs by tab id, instead the tab index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var SelectedTab = $('ul li#yourId').index();

$( ".selector" ).tabs({ selected: SelectedTab  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this maybe:

```
   //executes on load
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({ selected: 2 });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could tap into the `create` event and select a tab by id there:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    create: function() {
        $(this).tabs("select", "#tabs-2");
    }
});
```